# How to CALL a procedure in Google BigQuery from Google Cloud Scheduler

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-scheduler

I am using Cloud Scheduler to trigger queries more frequently than 15 minutes.
I have created a procedure in BigQuery called: `project-id.dataset.procedure`
This procedure CREATE OR REPLACE-s a table in BigQuery from 20 different data sources.

In BigQuery, the following SQL works:

CALL `project-id.dataset.procedure`();
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project-id.dataset.newtable` AS SELECT column1 FROM `project-id.dataset.tablename` WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL

However, when I send the 'CALL' via Cloud Scheduler, BigQuery API is returning an 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error from the following JSON payload:

{
"query": "CALL `project-id.dataset.procedure`();",
"useLegacySql": false
}

The project id, dataset, procedure name are all spelled correctly.

I don't think it's an authentication or permissions issue, as the following JSON payload **works**:

{
"query": "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project-id.dataset.newtable` AS SELECT column1 FROM `project-id.dataset.tablename` WHERE column1 IS NOT NULL",
"useLegacySql": false
}

Notes:

- Content-Type is 'application/json'
- Target Type is HTTP
- HTTP Method is POST
- OAuth token works for the second-listed JSON Query

I've tried "userLegacySql": true and I've upped the service account's role to 'Owner' as well as 'BigQuery Admin'. All to no avail. Still getting 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right syntax for calling procedure, using bq or cloud scheduler, the project id should be between GRAVE ACCENT`` and not APOSTROPHE''.

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CALL `project-id`.dataset.yourprocedure()'
```